# Find lines matching regex and select a different part of the line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have two lines like below:

> /pace =builtin\administrators  Type=0x0 Flags=0x13 AccessMask=0x1f01ff 
>   /pace =domain\user  Type=0x0 Flags=0x13 AccessMask=0x1f01ff

Need to create a regular expression where it only select `0x1f01ff` where the line have `domain\user`.

This is what I have created but it select `/pace =domain\user  Type=0x0 Flags=0x13 AccessMask=`:

> ^(.+domain(.*)accessmask=)

Comment: Mere selection surely isn't your ultimate goal.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
^.+domain\\user.+AccessMask=([^\s]+)
```

It matches any line that has domain\user and then get the value of accessmask (any character that is not a whitespace)